# JavaScript array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have written a block of typescript code.

```
CreateArray():any []
 {
  console.log("start");
    var array = [];
    var nameObjects = ["dave", "mike", "dave1", "mike1"];
       for (var j = 0; j < nameObjects.length; j++) {
          for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
                array.push({
                    "hour": i, 
                    nameObjects
                })
            }
        }
        console.log(array);
        return array;
}
```

the output will be something like this:

```
{
hour: 1,
nameObjects :{"dave", "mike", "dave1", "mike1"}
},

 {
 hour: 2,
 nameObjects :{"dave", "mike", "dave1", "mike1"} 
 }
```

.....

```
{hour: 9,
  nameObjects :{"dave", "mike", "dave1", "mike1"} }
 }
```

I want the output to be like:

```
 {
hour: 1,
 dave:0,
 mike:0, 
 dave1:0,
 mike1:0
},
{
hour: 2,
 dave:0,
 mike:0, 
 dave1:0,
 mike1:0
},
```

I have tried to fix it but I couldn't. Please help to overcome this issue

Comment: everything inside { } counts as single object and not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
console.log("start");
var array = [];
var nameObjects = ["dave", "mike", "dave1", "mike1"];

for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    var item = {
        hour: i
    };

    for (var j = 0; j < nameObjects.length; j++) {
        item[nameObjects[j]] = 0;
    }       
    array.push(item);
}

console.log(array);
```

[[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=console.log(%22start%22)%3B%0Avar%20array%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0Avar%20nameObjects%20%3D%20%5B%22dave%22%2C%20%22mike%22%2C%20%22dave1%22%2C%20%22mike1%22%5D%3B%0A%0Afor%20(var%20i%20%3D%201%3B%20i%20%3C%209%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%09var%20item%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09%09hour%3A%20i%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%09%0A%09for%20(var%20j%20%3D%200%3B%20j%20%3C%20nameObjects.length%3B%20j%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%09%09item%5BnameObjects%5Bj%5D%5D%20%3D%200%3B%0A%09%7D%09%09%0A%09array.push(item)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(array)%3B%0A)]

Comment: Martin Vseticka, yes, that what I wanted. YOU are the man of the day